# OpenVAS scanner TIMEOUT

Tags: linux, security, centos-7

The scanner was working just fine until I ran a task with 58 targets (CSV file) and the deafult Maximum concurrently scanned hosts = 20, the load got way too high and I couldn't log back on or risk to let it run and happen something to the targets so I just ran "**service openvas-scanner stop**", it did stop but now I can't bring it back on.

I have no clue what to do now and haven't found anything usefull online, I don't wanna start it all over for a stop command....

The status:

```
root@OPENVAS: systemctl status openvas-scanner.service
● openvas-scanner.service - LSB: remote network security auditor - scanner
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/openvas-scanner; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Qua 2019-01-16 17:20:13 -02; 29min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1173 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/openvas-scanner start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 3.8M
      CPU: 54ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/openvas-scanner.service
           └─1208 /usr/sbin/openvassd

Jan 16 17:15:12 OPENVAS systemd[1]: Starting LSB: remote network security auditor - scanner...
Jan 16 17:15:14 OPENVAS openvas-scanner[1173]: (openvassd:1208): lib  kb_redis-CRITICAL **: fetch_max_db_index: cannot retr
Jan 16 17:20:13 OPENVAS systemd[1]: openvas-scanner.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 16 17:20:13 OPENVAS systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: remote network security auditor - scanner.
Jan 16 17:20:13 OPENVAS systemd[1]: openvas-scanner.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 16 17:20:13 OPENVAS systemd[1]: openvas-scanner.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

When I try to start:

```
root@OPENVAS systemctl start openvas-scanner.service
Job for openvas-scanner.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status openvas-scanner.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

.

journalctl -xe

```
root@OPENVAS: journalctl -xe
Jan 16 18:15:17 OPENVAS sudo[1796]: root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/run/redis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/openvasmd --rebuild
Jan 16 18:15:17 OPENVAS sudo[1796]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Jan 16 18:17:01 OPENVAS CRON[1815]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 16 18:17:01 OPENVAS CRON[1816]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 16 18:17:01 OPENVAS CRON[1815]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 16 18:29:36 OPENVAS sudo[1796]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 16 18:29:45 OPENVAS systemd[1]: Starting LSB: remote network security auditor - scanner...
-- Subject: Unidade openvas-scanner.service sendo iniciado
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade openvas-scanner.service está sendo iniciada.
Jan 16 18:34:45 OPENVAS systemd[1]: openvas-scanner.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 16 18:34:45 OPENVAS systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: remote network security auditor - scanner.
-- Subject: A unidade openvas-scanner.service falhou
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade openvas-scanner.service falhou.
--
-- O resultado é failed.
Jan 16 18:34:45 OPENVAS systemd[1]: openvas-scanner.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 16 18:34:45 OPENVAS systemd[1]: openvas-scanner.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Revisit your Redis setup with the resources mentioned above. The following steps are known to work and to solve this issue:**

Delete the file dump.rdb (Located in e.g. /var/run/redis depending on your setup)
Comment out/remove all save xy z (e.g. save 900 1) from your redis.conf (Located in e.g. /etc/redis depending on your setup)
Optional: Flush your redis database (Depending on your setup, e.g. redis-cli -s /var/run/redis/redis.sock flushall)
Restart redis (Depending on your setup, e.g. service redis-server restart)
Restart the Scanner (openvassd) and try again

Temporary solution which is flushing the redis-cli databases
with flushall command and restart the scanner to retrieve the NVTs.
Here are the steps to check if you have databases which are
not used :

```
$ redis-cli -s <path_to_redis_socket>
> INFO keyspace
```